# Limiting Image upload extension to jpg in older browsers(e.g. IE9)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

I followed the link above to restrict my image upload extension to jpeg, jpg and I have these lines in my script:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath, new { type = "file", accept = "image/jpeg,  image/jpg"}) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath)

// for multiple file select
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath, new { type = "file", accept = "image/jpeg,   image/jpg", multiple = "multiple" })
```

}

However, I'm stuck with the problem that the user can still upload any image type when using IE9 and older versions. Is there something else I can use to restrict IE9 and older browsers to uploading only jpg images?

Also, the link mentions validation on the server side. What can I do on the server side to restrict image upload extension to only jpg?

I'm using VS2012 ASP .NET MVC4.

Comment: *hat can I do on the server side* Check the type?

Comment: on the server, check the extension of the uploaded file, then test if it is a valid jpg.

Comment: I can do that on the client side but I heard someone can rename the file to virus.jpg and it'll pass?